# Why is memory-sink pulled to the driver and hence restricted in size to be small?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

just trying to get a grasp on how to work with spark structured streaming I found the memory sink (+ complete mode for aggregations) most useful for interactive work with spark in jupyter-notebook or the like.

However it says that it only works for small aggregated tables. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks

That sounds super awkward, as spark is kind of the reference implementation of large in memory dataframes.
Is it planned to support full-sized in memory tables, with all modes (append, complete, update)?

Is there a workaround currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to "why" is simple - memory sink is primarily a debugging and is not intended for production use:

> This should be used for debugging purposes

As of the other question:

> Is it planned to support full-sized in memory tables, with all modes (append, complete, update)?

Optimally this would require support for low latency, mutable tables and such structures are at the moment out of Spark's scope, and not seriously considered (although some proprietary extensions that try this direction exist).

It is safe to assume that such option won't exist in the immediate future (Spark 3.0), but of course it might be introduced later.